# Being called Buddhist

Tags: right-view, western-buddhism, wrongview, politics

I always wondered why do people that practice Buddhist practices, label or opt not to label themselves "Buddhist".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should one call oneself a Buddhist?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3511/157)

Comment: Uilium, do you think the questions are duplicate (i.e. do the answers to that question answer your question)? Or are they slightly different (e.g. that one is asking whether they should, and this one is asking why they do)? If you don't think they're duplicate, is this one [a "polling" question of the sort that's usually off-topic](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/1572/254) (e.g. are you asking everyone to explain why they do or don't label themselves)?

Comment: @ChrisW Ok, I think I should reword it. Maybe put it on hold  until I can get to it later.

Answer (score 1):

All labels are conventions & attachment to mental states of non-becoming can make the mind uncomfortable with conventions.

Also, the term 'Buddhist' is a stereotype, loaded with all kinds of worldly connotations, such as believing in the Dalai Lama, reincarnation, statues, etc.

Those people might be more comfortable if asked: "Do you practise the teachings (path) of the Buddha?".